# php to execute powershell

Tags: php, powershell

I am trying to invoke a commmand on powershell in my php script.
Below is the code I have.

The powershell code is being invoked on a remote machine:

```
exec("Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command Invoke-Command -ComputerName computer.domain.net \\Computer.domain.net\ta\Waitandreload.ps1");
```

However, this does not work.

When I run the below code in my powershell (x64 and x86), it works fine even without running powershell as admin.

```
Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command Invoke-Command -ComputerName computer.domain.net \\Computer.domain.net\ta\Waitandreload.ps1
```

Any help is appreciated.

Below is the code I have

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile) && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['mappingfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadmappingfile) && in_array($ext,$allowed) && in_array($mappingext,$allowed)) 
        {
            echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.";

/*          $query = "INSERT INTO tafileuploadmapping (CustomerName, TicketSheet, MappingSheet) 
              VALUES('$customername', '$uploadfile', '$uploadmappingfile')";
            mysqli_query($db, $query);
            //$_SESSION['success'] = "File Now Uploaded"; 
*/
            exec("Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command Invoke-Command -ComputerName computer.domain.net \\computer.domain.net\ta\Waitandreload.ps1",$out,$ret);
            echo "running till powershell command";
            print_r($out);
            echo "</n>";
            print_r($ret);
```

The output I get when this runs is as follows:

> File is valid, and was successfully uploaded. running till powershell commandArray ( ) 1

Comment: *"This doesn't work"* what happens?

Comment: Well, can you help me how I can debug this?
I tried adding $out and $ret at the end of the syntax and am echoing those like follows:

echo ($out);
echo "</n>";
echo ($ret);

But there is nothing getting echoed

Comment: For starters, tell us *how* it's not working (error messages? gives wrong results?)

Comment: The powershell code is not getting executed..

Comment: And your log or standard output (is this a page or a CLI application?) says nothing?

Comment: I have no error codes. No return statements once the php code runs. So basically I don't know how to debug

Comment: Again, is this a web app or a CLI app?

Comment: Okay hold on. Let me add the code and the output below

Comment: It's a webapp (webpage built on xampp) which triggers a powershell.

Comment: Now that I look better, there are a lot of backslashes (`\``) in your command-line string. You should escape them (`\\\`).

Comment: Did you mean backslash ( \ ) or backslash ( ` )?
I dont see (`) in my code.

Comment: Sorry, formatting messed it up. I meant "\" and "\\".

Comment: So this is what I should change my code to?

Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command Invoke-Command -ComputerName computer.domain.net \\computer.domain.net\\ta\\Waitandreload.ps1",$out,$ret

Comment: \\computer.domain.net should actually be \\\\computer.domain.net